# How to use "r" or "b" or the likes with variables, not literals?

Tags: rust

I can do this:

```
 Regex::new(r"some reg exp")
```

However, how can I use "r" and dynamically created string together, that is, a variable?

```
 let reg_str = get_some_reg_exp();
 Regex::new(r  reg_str????)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this hypothetical syntax?

Comment: @Shepmaster, guess my friend.

Comment: I apologize, I must have been unclear. The syntax `r reg_str` doesn't make any sense. A string variable doesn't need any special escaping, it's just a handle to a thing. What **problem** do you have that you think this syntax would solve?

Comment: @Shepmaster, I want to get the same output string as I do when I use "r". But with a string being variable. Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: It doesn't make sense because `r` only has anything to do with how the compiler reads a string literal. Once things are inside a string, that part is over and done with and the contents are the same. So if you're getting your regex from a function, you can just pass the result of that function into `Regex::new` and it'll work.

Comment: @MatthewWalton, thx. so what characters does "r" change?

Comment: Using `r` stops `\` being special, so you can't use something like `\n` to get a newline in a raw string literal. It also changes how `"` is interpreted as the end of a string - if you want `"` inside a raw string literal, you can add some hashes to the delimiters: `r#" my string with a " in it "#`, or as many hashes as you like (provided the count is the same at each end). So with that you can put basically anything at all inside a raw string literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `r""` (raw string) and `b""` (byte) only make sense for literals - they're part of literal string syntax.  Think of them as a different type of quote - it wouldn't make sense to use plain double quotes (`""`) with non-literals.

The only difference between `r"blah"` and `"blah"` is that some special characters are escaped differently; the result is still an object of type `&'static str`.

Byte string literals (`b"foo"`) and raw byte string literals (`br"foo"`) are analogous, but are `&'static [u8;n]`.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense with variables?

Comment: I thought my answer covered it. Can you say how you think it might change  a variable?